# How to draw google map with driving direction using two set of co-ordinates for web

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want add a Google embed map in my website with driving direction, I have two sets of co-ordinates of start point and end point (39.5368782,-104.8778400) (39.6295396,-104.8921668). I have attached a sample view of the map. The co-ordinates will change in each page

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: sure, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I have tried  but did't get any code for the same.

Comment: People who will be answering (I for example), would like to see some summary of what is done so far... Stackoverflow users prefer questions with maximum own try first.. That's why your q has downvotes so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will be helpful for implement the same

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
              <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Directions service</title>
                <style>
                  html, body, #map-canvas {
                    height: 100%;
                    margin: 0px;
                    padding: 0px
                  }
                  #panel {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 5px;
                    left: 50%;
                    margin-left: -180px;
                    z-index: 5;
                    background-color: #fff;
                    padding: 5px;
                    border: 1px solid #999;
                  }
                </style>
                <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
                <script>
            var directionsDisplay;
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var map;

            function initialize() {
              directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
              var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
              var mapOptions = {
                zoom:7,
                center: chicago
              };
              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
              directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            }

            function calcRoute() {
              var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
              var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
              var request = {
                  origin:start,
                  destination:end,
                  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
              };
              directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
              });
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

                </script>
              </head>
              <body>
                <div id="panel">
                <b>Start: </b>
                <select id="start" onchange="calcRoute();">
                  <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
                  <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
                  <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
                  <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
                  <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
                  <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
                  <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
                  <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
                  <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
                  <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
                  <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
                  <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
                </select>
                <b>End: </b>
                <select id="end" onchange="calcRoute();">
                  <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
                  <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
                  <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
                  <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
                  <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
                  <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
                  <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
                  <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
                  <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
                  <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
                  <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
                  <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div id="map-canvas"></div>
              </body>
            </html>
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple